# How to append popup from background js to current active content page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I make a timer extension that runs in the background js. After the timer times up, I want a popup appear on the content page.
the popup appear when i stay in the same tab i start the timer, but it doesn't work if I move to a different tab.
I already tried tab query with active and/or currentwindow true, but it still doesnt work when I move to another tab.

I want it to works even though I move tab.

Comment: You'll need to chrome.tabs.onActivated event in the background script. Inside that event you'll send a message to the new tab so it creates the popup if it wasn't present or just updates it if it was.